# MVC 3/EF/SQL Server strange connection timeout issue

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller, exception, timeout, repository

Before reading please note that I've googled this and read a ton of articles on SO and elsewhere, no suggestions have worked as of yet.

I'm randomly getting a timeout error that occurs when logging into my MVC 3 application. It happens well over half of the time - all other times the application logs on just fine. When it doesn't work, it tries for about 10 seconds then errors.

**The error:**

Exception: "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."
Inner Exception: {"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.\r\nTimeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}

This happens inside my repository class that directly interacts with entity framework.

---

It seems to happen when logging in and simply pulling a quick check from the database, such as:

```
 return entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.UserName == userName);

 return (entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.UserId || u.UserName == user.UserName) != null);
```

**Things I've tried:**

- SQL Server validation
- Integrated Security (I even gave every possible account full database access)
- Running outside of IIS
- Setting Connect Timeout extremely high (Connect Timeout=50000) in the connection string. (I do not have Default Command Timeout set here)
- Setting the CommandTimeout to 0, 5000, 100000, whatever, on my entity connection: entities.CommandTieout = 100000;
- Setting the CommandTimeout inside every using statement where I use an instance of the repository.
- Flipping SingleOrDefault to FirstOrDefault etc.
- Enabling/Disabling Lazy Loading (Why not?)

---

**If it helps:**

- I am using a custom role and membership provider.
- I'm just making calls from my controller inside a using statement (AccountRepository bleh = new AccountRepository()) and the AccountRepository implements IDisposable etc.
- The entity model is in a separate project.
- I'm running the site in IIS. It's setup with the 4.0 integrated app pool.
- All accounts have full database access.
- When the error occurs, it doesn't take no where near as long as I have set in the web config (50000 I think) or for the commandtimeout in the repository.
- It's not doing much on the login, just validating user, getting user role then loading up some small amount data, but the error always occurs when getting the user data on login.
- When I try it outside of debugging it repeats the error four or five times (with custom errors off).

Here is the full exception from the event log:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: SqlException 
Exception message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Comment: Where is the DB server in relation to the web server, maybe you are having network issues

Comment: Can you examine the problem from the database server by setting up a SQL Server Profiler?

Comment: Ben - I am running SQL Server 2008 directly on my development machine currently.

DOK - I will check into that ... I'm not too familiar with the profiler but will look into it.

Comment: @AndroidTaco, if you are using Code First make sure that your connection string name attribute is the same as your DbContext class name.

Comment: @bdparrish - The connection string name attribute is indeed the same as my DbContext class name. The logon process works sometimes, but I would say that it fails more than it succeeds.

Comment: what is the RAM, Processor, etc. on your Dev Computer?  I would run through the profiler as @DOK suggested.  That doesn't sound right if it is intermittent.  Did you change anything recently that would cause mass amounts of processing time on the SQL server?  New relationships between objects?  .Includes() that are happening during the login, that might be getting attached to the user?

Comment: @bdparrish - My dev box has 4GB of RAM/Core i7 CPU/64-bit Windows 7 Pro w/ SP1/SQL Server 2008. I haven't changed anything that would require massive amounts of processing time. When it fails the entire process involves creating an instance of the repository and simply returning a tiny amount of data as you see above. There are no new relationships, .Includes() etc. Side note: This also happens on other machines after publishing the site to them and running in IIS (SQL on same machine).

Comment: You can find lots of info about SQL Profiler by just googling around. Here's a site with a video that might help you get started http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_SQL_Server_Profiler

Comment: @DOK - Thank you for the link, I will definitely look into utilizing the profiler to examine from the DB perspective.

Comment: So from my currently limited knowledge of SQL profiler, when the error occurs, it appears that the profiler doesn't log anything ... it's not seeing any attempt to pull data being made. Does that help? I'll continue looking into it.

Comment: Also - it 'appears' that resetting IIS helps resolve the issue for a while.

Comment: Just to let everyone know - I believe that I have found the issue. Through the SQL Profiler, I saw that the account being used to access SQL was in fact the local system account. I then realized that in an attempt to fix an issue prior, I had changed the ASP.NET v4.0 app pool to use the local system account. I went and changed the Identity back to 'ApplicationPoolIdentity', added the IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 user to the database and so far everything has been working great. @DOK - Thank you much for the information on SQL Profiler, it helped tremendously! Thanks everyone else also!

Comment: I put my comments into an answer so you can accept it. That will help future readers of the question to zero in on the solution to your problem. I'm so glad Profiler helped you figure it out -- another great tool for your toolbox.

Comment: Thanks again - Talk about a learning experience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could examine the problem from the database server by setting up a **SQL Server Profiler**.

You can find lots of info about SQL Profiler by just googling around. Here's a [site with a video that might help you get started.](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_SQL_Server_Profiler)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: While this did indeed help me it was not the solution. The problem still exists for anyone reading in the future.**

Just to let everyone know - I believe that I have found the issue. Through the SQL Profiler, I saw that the account being used to access SQL was in fact the local system account. I then realized that in an attempt to fix an issue prior, I had changed the ASP.NET v4.0 app pool to use the local system account. I went and changed the Identity back to 'ApplicationPoolIdentity', added the IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 user to the database and so far everything has been working great. @DOK - Thank you much for the information on SQL Profiler, it helped tremendously! Thanks everyone else also!